# Archivos personales al instalar MiniOS

Tags: windows

Estaba empezando a instalar Windows 10 Pro MiniOS, y quería saber si, cuando lo instalo, todos mis archivos personales se borran? ¿O solo los programas? Eso solamente. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre depende, hay una opcion para cuando instalas , guardan todo el contenido de la carpeta de usuario en una carpeta llamada "Windows.Old" , en el disco donde estas instalando minios , si queres esto , realiza los siguientes pasos

- Bootea desde el pendrive
- Una vez estes en la gui de instalacion , selecciona la particion a donde quieras instalar pero no formatees (Si no borraras toda tu informacion)